# WebPush PushSubscription vs messaging.getToken?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, push, web-push

Good day.
I implement on the site a subscription for push notifications.
I can not figure out what the difference between the two approaches.

The first is to simply get the token and send it to the server, then send messages by accessing it

```js
function subscribe() {
  // запрашиваем разрешение на получение уведомлений
  messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function () {
      // получаем ID устройства
      messaging.getToken()
        .then(function (currentToken) {
          console.log(currentToken);

          if (currentToken) {
            sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
          } else {
            console.warn('Не удалось получить токен.');
            setTokenSentToServer(false);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.warn('При получении токена произошла ошибка.', err);
          setTokenSentToServer(false);
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.warn('Не удалось получить разрешение на показ уведомлений.', err);
    });
}
```

The second is to get the object PushSubscription and use what he returned to send messages

```js
function subscribeUserToPush() {
  return navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
  .then(function(registration) {
    var subscribeOptions = {
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: btoa(
        'BEl62iUYgUivxIkv69yViEuiBIa-Ib9-SkvMeAtA3LFgDzkrxZJjSgSnfckjBJuBkr3qBUYIHBQFLXYp5Nksh8U'
      )
    };

    return registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
  })
  .then(function(pushSubscription) {
    console.log('PushSubscription: ', JSON.stringify(pushSubscription));
    return pushSubscription;
  });
}

{
  "endpoint": "https://domain.pushservice.com/some-id",
  "keys": {
    "p256dh":
"BIPUL12DLfytvTajnryr3PJdAgXS3HGMlLqndGcJGabyhHheJYlNGCeXl1dn18gSJ1WArAPIxr4gK0_dQds4yiI=",
    "auth":"FPssMOQPmLmXWmdSTdbKVw=="
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is only for Google Firebase, the second one is the Web Standard API. I would highly recommend using the second one.

Here you are the main problems you can run into. [link](https://medium.com/@madridserginho/how-to-handle-webpush-api-pushsubscriptionchange-event-in-modern-browsers-6e47840d756f)